# PHP Can't keep changes made to a variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array where I keep some initial values. On the same page, in another php tag, I want to add more values to the array, when I press `get_more_items`.

**1st PHP tag**

```
<?php 
   $solution_files = array();
   ... assigning initial values...
?>
```

On the same page I have another php tag, where I want to modify the value of $solution_files:

**2nd PHP tag**

```
<?php
     if (isset($_GET["get_more_items"])){   
        //add more values to the $solution_files               
     }
     // new values visible here
?>
```

In the last php tag, where I want to list my array ($solution_files), I only see the values assigned to it in the first php tag, but not the new values I added after my search (get_more_items).

**3rd PHP tag**

```
<?php
     if (isset($_GET["display_results"])){  
        print_r($solution_files) 
        // it only displays the values I had initially               
     }
?>
```

What can I do to keep the new values I assigned in the second tag, when I ask for "Get more items"?

Comment: Can you please also share the code where you assign the values and add more values?

Comment: How do you assign the values?

Comment: Do you mean across multiple page loads or in the same page load?

Comment: @Adi Ulici, I take the values from a database. I run a query for the last 5 entried and add them to $solution_files.
`foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {

          //get row id, assign value to $solution_files[row_id] = **value**}`

Comment: The problem I see here is that when I press "Display Results", I lose all the changes that were made when I pressed "Get more items".

Comment: @GordonM , same page loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make a session array like this

**1st PHP Tag**

```
<?php 
   if(!isset($_SESSION['solution_files']))
   {
     $_SESSION['solution_files'] = array();

       ... assigning initial values...
       .. like ..
        $_SESSION['solution_files'][] "some value"; 
    }
?>
```

**2nd PHP Tag**

```
<?php 
   if (isset($_GET["get_more_items"])){   
    //add more values to the $solution_files  
       .. like ..
        $_SESSION['solution_files'][] "some more value"; 
    }
?>
```

**3rd PHP Tag**

```
<?php 
   if (isset($_GET["display_results"])){  
       print_r($_SESSION['solution_files']) 
       // it only displays the values I had initially               

    }
?>
```

**NOTE:** before using session in php you have to start session at top of your page. like

```
session_start();
```

Comment: You're assuming the OP means they can't preserve state across page loads.  That's not stated anywhere in the question.  You also don't session_start() anywhere

Comment: @GordonM i think this should we have to left on OP's choice. and about `session_start()` it is not hard to understand that the session can be used when session starts but if you have doubt i will update it.

Comment: @SKRocks  thank you so much! Followed your suggestions and it worked like a charm! I must confess, I wasn't familiar with session variables, so it didn't even cross my mind to use them. Thanks again